# Multiple select statements with multiple selected results in Single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to link multiple selects into one query i have looked at another thread on here which helped greatly but this only accounts for single select options like so.

```
  SELECT  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   user_table
    ) AS tot_user,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   cat_table
    ) AS tot_cat,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   course_table
    ) AS tot_course
```

but my issue is that i am trying to get multiple options from each select like so.

```
SELECT (
SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated',
) AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated',
(
SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Web Cases Generated'
) AS 'No. of Web Cases Generated'
```

I keep getting the error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

From what i have read this is because i am trying to link 3 different values under one selector which i dont want to do.

This bit of code at the end is what the problem is.

```
) AS 'No. of Web Cases Generated'
```

I have tried this to resolve but obviously am missing the expertise to get it right.

```
) "" AS Company,
  "" AS Username,
  "" AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated',
  AS 'No. of Web Cases Generated'
```

This doesnt work as it doesnt know what value to allocate to what selector.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a `FROM` clause on your sub-queries.

Comment: They are just examples of the select values as the full queries are very long. the queries are tested and working on there own but i need to like them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's correct behavior since you are actually trying to merge multiple column values in single column which is not possible

```
( SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated',
) AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated',
```

Think what you are looking for is a `UNION` rather like

```
SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated'
FROM some_table  --first part of query

UNION            -- combine the data

SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Web Cases Generated'
FROM some_other_table;  -- second part of query
```

Per your comment, perform a `JOIN` then

```
select xx.Company, xx.Username,xx.'No. of Private Cases Generated',
xxx.Company1, xxx.Username1, xxx.'No. of Web Cases Generated'
FROM (
SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Private Cases Generated',
FROM some_table  ) xx

JOIN (
SELECT c.name AS Company,
CONCAT(UPPER(u.forename),' ', u.surname) AS Username,
count(c.case) AS 'No. of Web Cases Generated'
FROM some_other_table ) xxx
ON xx.Company = xxx.Company;
```

Comment: Is there a way to link the multple values to the multiple columns please ?

Comment: Would the union bring the private and web back as seperate values though or would it merge them ??

Comment: @troggy69, it will merge the two result set into one result set.

Comment: I need the table to look like

Company | Username | Private case | Web case

Comment: Genius Thank you ! :)